# Centered layout with div borders on left and right (with bg images) (drupal)

Tags: html, css, drupal

I have begun a new theme on drupal using the Boilerplate theme.
I am trying to achieve a centered(responsive width) layout with borders on both left and right sides. I have attached a diagram. [DIAGRAM HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUscf.jpg)

I have the left side borders  working fine, they are within the #PAGE div which is the one and only WRAPPER of all content. (there is no other div above it)

As i have shown in the diagram, i am having trouble with the RIGHT side borders. With the same CSS syntax as the left borders, you can see they are positioned all the way to the right, even though they are inside the #PAGE div. Why is this? why is the #PAGE div not pulling it together?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT
`code`[jsFiddle demo/mockup](https://jsfiddle.net/rbptv8v1/)

PS- these 'borders' need to hold images as backgrounds so i can not simply use the 'border' property. And the 'border-image' is not well supported. DIV's is what i need.

Comment: This seems to achieve what you want http://jsfiddle.net/t1awx9m3/. No promises though!

Comment: And a slightly better one! http://jsfiddle.net/t1awx9m3/1/

Comment: @PedroKTFC This i can see works very well but when i tried putting it down on Drupal it wasnt working. Not sure why. Pressed for time so havent investigated.
Thanks to cFreed, this works. https://jsfiddle.net/rbptv8v1/1/

Comment: No worries @tacss. I can appreciate getting it into Drupal would not be trivial. As for the solution you gave, I would only comment that it's not perfectly responsive when you shrink things down too extremely, although it is very close. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your right border has "position:fixed", which means that its position is relative to the viewport and not to the HTML content. So with

```
right:0
```

...it will be pushed on the right edge of the browser window (0 pixel from the right side of the window). You need to keep it the normal flow (so avoid position fixed or absolute, use relative).

You will also get into trouble to be responsive with fixed borders.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position for more infos.

You can also try to do this using css borders property : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border.

Good luck with this.